# jquery html() give out only first value used with each () method

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

In the following code, using jquery's each() and html() inserts only the first div value i.e. "David Smith" in the whole array (all_names[]) wheres I expected each() to iterate over each div and insert their corresponding value into corresponding array index.

More than code correction, I prefer if anybody can tell me the reason behind such behavior of each() or html() function (I'm not sure). I am a beginner in jQuery and this will help me strengthen my understanding of jquery.

Thanks
dkj

**HTML**

```
<div class="test"><a href="#">David Smith</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="#">Adam John </a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="#">Tina Samara </a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="#">James White </a></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var all_names = [];
    var total_names = $('div.test a');

    total_names.each(
        function() {
             all_names[counter] = total_names.html();
             counter++;
        }
    );      

 alert("total Names: " + all_names);

 </script>
```

Comment: `total_names.eq(counter).html()`  But `all_names` is an array, so alerting it won't give you anyway expected result. Many things seems wrong in your code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the point of `each`. It iterates over array giving the current element in the array to its callback function as the second argument (first being the current index). Instead of calling `html` on the current element in the loop, you always call it on the entire matched list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var all_names = [];
    var total_names = $('div.test a');

    total_names.each(
        function(idx, elemInArray) {
             all_names[counter] = $(elemInArray).html();
             counter++;
        }
    );      

 alert("total Names: " + all_names);

 </script>
```

Also worth to note that in iterations of each, `this` is a reference to the current item. It can simplify accessing items like so

```
$(someArrayOfElements).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html()); // $(this) is the current item wrapped into a jQuery object
});
```

Comment: You made same error than other posted answer, am i wrong?!

Comment: It needs to be `$(elemInArray).html()` or `$(this).html()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use second argument of each function to achieve item

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var all_names = [];
   var total_names = $('div.test a');

   total_names.each(
       function(index, item) {
            all_names[counter] = $(item).html();
            counter++;
       }
   );      

 alert("total Names: " + all_names);

 </script>
```

Comment: `item` is the index here, needs to be e.g: `each(function(_, item){...})`

Comment: `item` is not a jQuery object, it's a DOM element. You need to use `$(item).html()`.

Comment: Yes Barmar is right. Works only with `$(item).html()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map()` instead of `.each()`

```
var all_names = total_names.map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

`.get()` is needed at the end to convert the jQuery collection that `.map()` returns to an ordinary array.